# Calculate "The Latest log-off time - The Earliest Log in time"

Tags: windows-7, login, logging

I am using a windows- 7 machine for my work. I log in everyday, do some work and then log off. I take a few short breaks in between when I Lock (Windows+L) my laptop.

I have to account for the number of hours worked by the end of the week which means the time for which I was logged in to this machine.

The problem is that I do complete all the work that is assigned to me, but I forget to keep track of the exact hours I was logged into this machine. I may have logged in at 5 am in the morning and then logged off at 3 in the afternoon- and I dont have any manual logs of my time.

Is there someplace where windows keep a weekly track of

Say per day:

"The Latest log-off time - The Earliest Log in time" into that system for a particular day. I only need these logs for a week.

any heads up would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [Tracking User Logon Activity Using Logon Events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericfitz/archive/2008/08/20/tracking-user-logon-activity-using-logon-events.aspx)

Comment: [Track user logons with a PowerShell script](https://4sysops.com/archives/track-user-logons-with-a-powershell-script/)